# Date field value is changing after saving data to database

Tags: c#, sql-server

when i am saving the "date value" to sql server table from C# project, it is always saving as - `1894-06-27 00:00:00.000` - in the database table.

The datatype of the table column field is `datetime`.

Just before saving to database, the query string contains `"17/11/2017"` - as the DoB value. But after saved to database, the date of birth column value becomes    `1894-06-27 00:00:00:000.` How to solve this ?

Comment: Can you show your c# code that does the saving?

Comment: string sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_CarBooking (CarID, EmpID, BookingDate, ReservationToDate, ReservationEndDate, BookingStatus) VALUES (" + SelectedCar.CarID + "," + SelectedEmployee.EmployeeID + ", " + DateTime.Now.ToString("d") + "," + ToDate.ToString("d") + "," + EndDate.ToString("d") + ", 0); ";

bool saved = dataaccess.Save(sql);